# Create a long sideways table with strict formatting specifications

Tags: longtable, rotating, landscape, sidewaystable

I know this questions is asked quit frequently but somehow now way of them seems working for me.

I have a template from my university for what my tables should look like:

```
\documentclass[%
    fontsize=11pt, 
    twoside=off 
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage[tablewithout, figurewithout]{caption} 

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8} 
\newcolumntype{M}{X<{\vspace{4pt}}} 

\begin{document}

\vspace{\parskip}
\section*{Überschrift Tabelle 1}

\begin{table}[!h]
\fontsize{9pt}{13pt}\selectfont
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ M | M }
\multicolumn{1}{X}{\textbf{Spalte 1}}%
& \multicolumn{1}{X}{\textbf{Spalte 2}} \\
\hline
Nummer 1,\newline\,mehrzeilig in Schriftgröße 9 pt & Nummer 2 \\
\hline
Nummer 1 & Nummer 2 \\
\hline
Nummer 1 & Nummer 2 \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\caption{}
\end{table}



\vspace{\parskip}
\section*{Überschrift Tabelle 2}

\begin{table}[!h]
\fontsize{9pt}{13pt}\selectfont
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| M | M |}
\hline
\textbf{Spalte 1} & \textbf{Spalte 2} \\
\hline
Nummer 1 & Nummer 2 \\
\hline
Nummer 1 & Nummer 2 \\
\hline
Nummer 1 & Nummer 2 \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{}
\end{table}


\vspace{\parskip}
\section*{Überschrift Tabelle 3}

\begin{table}[!h]
\fontsize{9pt}{13pt}\selectfont
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} M  M @{}}
\textbf{Spalte 1} & \textbf{Spalte 2} \\
Nummer 1 & Nummer 2 \\
Nummer 1 & Nummer 2 \\
Nummer 1 & Nummer 2 \\
\end{tabularx}
\caption{}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]
(sorry that they are in german)

Now I have a table that is better displayed in landscape format. I have made it work with sidewaystable, but here the table only goes over one page.

My attempts to make the whole thing go over several pages always fail well beforehand.

this is my current attempt (with customized column widths):

```
\documentclass[%
    fontsize=11pt, 
    twoside=off 
]{scrbook} 

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage{tabularx} % Flexiblere Tabellen
\usepackage[tablewithout, figurewithout]{caption}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8} 
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{X<{\vspace{4pt}\hsize=#1\hsize}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!h]
\fontsize{9pt}{13pt}\selectfont
\begin{longtable}{\textwidth}{| M{0.5} | M{1} | M{1} | M{0.5} | M{0.5} | M{0.5} | M{1} |  M{1} | M{1} | M{3} |}

\hline
\textbf{id}  & \textbf{Label}                        & \textbf{Grund}                      & \textbf{Offen}   & \textbf{Durchfluss} & \textbf{Durchlass} & \textbf{Rückstau} & \textbf{HQ-Marken\footnote{Beachte: \gls{hq}}} & \textbf{Parkplatz}  &  \textbf{Notizen} \\
\hline
1 & & xy & xy & 0 & 0 & Ja & 0 & &  xxxxyyyyyy\\
\hline
*unbelivebale amount of data*
507 & xy  &  & xy & 0 & 0 & xy & 0  & xy & xxxxyyyyyy\\                  
\hline
\end{longtable}
\caption{xy \cite{xy}}
\label{xy}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Now I'm getting more and more error messages.
Starting with the fact that \texdwidth is an illegal Illegal pream-token, that the \hline is outside the table. And I quote:

> Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.

> You have written too many alignment tabs in a table, causing one of them to be turned into a line break. Make sure you have specified the correct number of columns in your table.

although I am pretty sure that this is not correct or must have another cause because this error does not occur with the normal sideway table.

Sorry for the long text and any help is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Long table had not to be encapsulated in `table` float, to longtable can not be prescribe width, it also have not defined `X` columns type, etc. It is not clear, how you would  like to deal with column headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To long for the comment:

- Sorry, frankly said, your code is mess. From it is impossible to figured out what you like to have in table
- Any kind of long table (`longtable`, `xltabuilar`, `longtblr` of `tabularray` etc.)= had not to be incapsulated to float `table`.
- Column type `X` is available only in `tabularx`, `xltabular`, `longtblr, etc. tables and not in` longtable`.
- According to your column specification, your table is quite wide. SO it fit in `landscape` page is fragile
- From your MWE is not evident, what is columns contents. It may be better that some column have natural width (in MWE below ˙`Q` columns instead of `X`.

An example of possible table, which may serve as starting point:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}% define page layout

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularray}


\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
    \footnotesize
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {xy},
  label = {xy},
note{a} = {Beachte: {hq}},  
                ]{hlines, vlines,
                  colspec = {X[0.5,l, font=\bfseries] 
                             *{8}{X[l]} 
                                  X[3,l]},
                  row{1}  = {font = \bfseries, m},
                  rowhead = 1}
% column deaders
i.d &   Label       &   Grund       &   Offen   &   Durchfluss  
    &   Durchlass   &   Rückstau    &   {HQ-\\Marken}\TblrNote{a}
                                                &   Parkplatz  
    &   Notizen     \\
1   & 2             & 3             & 4         & 5 
    & 6             & 7             & 8         & 9
    &  10: xxxxyyyyyy   \\
%*unbelivebale amount of data*
507 & xy            &               & xy        & 0 
    & 0             & xy            & 0         & xy 
    & xxxxyyyyyy        \\
\end{longtblr}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please, edit your question, remove all aforementioned flaws, and provide more (dummy) data in your table, which mimic real data. Also clarify, what is your problem, or where you stuck in writing your table. After this it will be possible better to help you.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for my messy code. It is my first time using LaTeX.

I'll work on it again tomorrow and then I'll send the question again.

Comment: Thank you very much! @Zarko this was exactly what I was looking for. 

I need to change a few things. (the caption needs to be at the bottom, and the "Continue "- message needs to be in German) but this is stuff I hopefully can do myself

Comment: @FloB, at long table are caption on the top of table (that it can be easy repeated on each page). This is at `tabularray` package default settings.  For different settings and other issues see `tabularray` package documentation or aske here on site. Happy TeXing!

Comment: Thank you again. You have helped me a lot. In the meantime, it looks the way it should look and I even managed to do the part with the `\DefTblrTemplate` on my own. I'm pretty proud of it. (Maybe more than I should be after all your help)

Comment: And just when I thought the table was finished, I got the idea that a link to the respective line could be very practical, since it is so long.

Will I ever finish the paper?

Comment: @FloB, it seems that you are very enthusiastic about table. At least you will learn a lot about `tabularray` . Sorry, I can't figured out what you now like to do with table. You may ask new question and in it describe new problem. Happy TeXing and happy and prosper 2024!